# Must I report a car accident to the police?

Tags: vehicle, motor-vehicle, accident, connecticut

I live in Connecticut, and that's also where I have my car registered.

If I get into a car accident in Connecticut, am I required by law to inform the police?

https://www.dmv.com/ct/connecticut/auto-accidents says:

> You are also required by law to inform the police immediately in case of any accident that involves death, injury or property damage.

But, I looked at [Title 14 of the General Statues of Connecticut](https://www.cga.ct.gov/current/pub/title_14.htm) and didn't see any law saying that.

Where's the law that says that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a reference to Section [14-224](https://www.cga.ct.gov/current/pub/chap_248.htm#sec_14-224):

> (a) Each operator of a motor vehicle who is knowingly involved in an accident which results in the death of any other person shall at once stop and render such assistance as may be needed and shall give such operator’s name, address and operator’s license number and registration number to any officer or witness to the death of any person, and if such operator of the motor vehicle causing the death of any person is unable to give such operator’s name, address and operator’s license number and registration number to any witness or officer, for any reason or cause, such operator shall immediately report such death of any person to a police officer, a constable, a state police officer or an inspector of motor vehicles or at the nearest police precinct or station, and shall state in such report the location and circumstances of the accident causing the death of any person and such operator’s name, address, operator’s license number and registration number.

There are subsequent similar paragraphs  about accidents resulting in injury or property damage.

The wording is a little bit confusing and it appears that you don't strictly have to report to the police, if you instead identify yourself to a witness.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you. :-) So, I guess that website is incorrect? According to subdivision (3) of subsection (b), for an accident that only results in property damage, which is actually the type of accident I was wondering about, you "shall" give your information to the owner of the damaged property "or" to a police officer. I think "shall" means "must" here, but I'm not sure. Anyway, it seems like you actually don't have to report such an accident to the police... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Note: the link you provided may be outdated. The current link is https://www.cga.ct.gov/current/pub/chap_248.htm#sec_14-224.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link.  Yes, I also don't see that you are specifically required to report the accident to the police, if you have already given your information to the property owner.  It could be that dmv.org is misstating the law, or that they know something we don't.  I think it's pretty clear that "shall" means "must".

Answer (score 0):

No, if there is a car accident that does not result in damage to any other person's property, then there is no requirement to report it to anyone.